# Extension cable for internal SD card reader

Tags: laptop, sd-card

I have card reader of Dell Inspiron 5520.

You can see it here: [Y0W97](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dell-Inspiron-15R-5520-Card-Reader-Board-w-Cable-Y0W97-/131206051266?hash=item1e8c7d75c2:g:3zAAAOSwnH1WY91C)

But the cable is not enough long.

There is any chance to buy extension for it? Or maybe buy longer cable and weld it?

Comment: Have you tried googling any of the numbers on the cable in the picture? From the rear view it looks like you can just plug in a new cable. Welding would be overkill.

Comment: @Burgi I think that it welded in the side of the reader. But anyway, How can I get such longer cable?

Comment: Try googling the numbers on the cable, one of them might be a part number or indicate the type of cable to search for.